# How does NoScript block inline scripts?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox-addon-webextensions, noscript

How do JavaScript blocking extensions like NoScript/ScriptSafe block inline scripts? For blocking request to remote scripts (i.e. for `<script src="http://example.com/index.js"></script>`) I can use `webRequest` API[1]. But that won't work for inline scripts.

I assume I could walk the dom and remove or somehow temporarily disable `<script>` blocks without `src` attribute, perhaps by renaming the element. I tried to dig into NoScript sources and noticed that it has content script with `"run_at": "document_start"` setting, which makes it run before the DOM is loaded and scripts are run.

Furthermore how can the extension prevent the case where an allowed script injects `<script>` tag with `src` pointing to blocked another domain 1 minute after page load?

[1] https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in ScriptSafe sources:

```
browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    response => {
        if (true) { // TODO check whether to block inline scripts for this HTML
            response.responseHeaders.push({
                'name': 'Content-Security-Policy',
                'value': "script-src 'none'"
            });
        }
        return response;
    }
    ,
    {
        'types': [ 'main_frame', 'sub_frame' ],
        'urls': [ '<all_urls>' ]
    },
    [
        'responseHeaders',
        'blocking'
    ]
);
```

The important part is adding an `Content-Security-Policy` header with value `script-src 'none'` which will prevent execution of inline JavaScript. This also blocks all remote scripts. See [1] for reference.

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src